# create a wav header for ADPCM recorded data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, header, wav, adpcm, ima4

My requirement is to create a .wav file, and I had an existing code with ADPCM encoder already written. It was getting data in linear PCM and converting it to ADPCM and creating a wave header for the file.

Now, I have modified the code, and I am getting the data directly into Apple ADPCM format, whose specific values are given below. How can I create a wave header for this file so I can play this file on any player. Right now, I am getting the file size correct, but it is not playing the data, neither full length, nor without crackling sound. Please suggest me any breakthroughs how can I debug the code, so I can get the exact problem. Currently it seems to be a problem of wave header to me.

**ADPCM Specifications used:**
**mSampleRate:**       44100

**mFormatID:**         kAudioFormatAppleIMA4

**mFormatFlags:**      0

**mChannelsPerFrame:** 2

**mBitsPerChannel:**   0

**mFramesPerPacket:**  64

**mBytesPerPacket:**   68 (= mChannelsPerFrame * 34)

**Wave Header Specifications used:**
**samplesPerSecond:**  44100

**channels:**          2

**status:**            0x0011U

**blockAlign:**        channels * 256

**bitsPerSample:**     4

**formatExtension:**   2

**samplesPerBLock:**   lsx_ima_samples_in((size_t) 0, (size_t) wavHeader.wChannels, (size_t) wavHeader.wBlockAlign, (size_t) 0);

**samplesWritten:**    self.audioLength/wavHeader.wSamplesPerBlock

**fmtSize:**           2 + wavHeader.wExtSize;

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.